# Which audio library to use?

Tags: c#, .net, audio, directsound

I want to build a .Net application for processing audio, and distribute it using ClickOnce deployment. I need access to a raw audio pipeline. Which audio library should I be using? I've heard the managed libraries for DirectSound are a dead end. I need as little as possible to be installed on the client's machine. Anything outside of the ClickOnce process isn't going to work.

NAudio might be a possibility, but isn't there potentially a separate driver install? There's also SlimDX.

It's a shame -- the managed DirectX libraries seem to work nicely and from what I've read, DirectX can be included in the ClickOnce install.

Comment: Also, I'll only be working with wave, PCM audio. I can control the exactly settings, sample frequency, encoding, etc.

Comment: I'm not getting what actual functionality you want. What's "access to a raw audio pipeline"? Do you want to catch audio data going through the Windows Multimedia system, and send audio data through that system?

Comment: If the managed DirectSound libs "seem to work nicely", why are they "a dead end"?

Comment: I use NAudio and I haven't heard about a separate driver install. NAudio to my knowledge is just a managed DLL.

Answer (score 1):

BASS : http://www.un4seen.com/
with Bass.Net is quite simple to use.

Comment: My prefered choice when .Net sound is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Although not free, [Alvas.Audio](http://alvas.net/alvas.audio,overview.aspx) may be worth looking at.

Answer (score 0):

OpenTK has an OpenAL implementation, but I'm not sure how it behaves with ClickOnce and it lacks reading/writing complex audio file formats(such as vorbis).